# the stuff of "compile project" can't be carried into the aar when publish to maven reporsitory

Tags: java, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I compile the `DemoProject:demo` with dependencies `compile 'cn.dreamtobe.android.phone:sdkproject-library:1.0.1`, it failed with following error tips:

```
Download http://mymaven.dreamtobe.cn:8081/artifactory/content/repositories/mobile/cn/dreamtobe/android/phone/sdkproject-library/1.0.0/sdkproject-library-1.0.1.pom

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':demo'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':demo:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find SDKProject:api:unspecified.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/Jacksgong/.m2/repository/SDKProject/api/unspecified/api-unspecified.pom
         file:/Users/Jacksgong/.m2/repository/SDKProject/api/unspecified/api-unspecified.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/SDKProject/api/unspecified/api-unspecified.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/SDKProject/api/unspecified/api-unspecified.jar
     Required by:
         DemoProject:demo:unspecified > cn.dreamtobe.android.phone:sdkproject-library:1.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 42.323 secs
```

So the real Question is:

### How to carry the stuff of `:api` module together rather than  just declare it in the `.pom` file when publishing the `:libray` module to the maven repo.

> since we can't find it in DemoProject, because of `':api'` just can be recognized in the SDKProject

My SDKProject hierarchy is:

```
SDKProject
|- library module(`:library`)
|- api module(`:api`)
```

and *library-module* dependent the *api-module*, bellow is `build.gradle` in the *library-module*

```
...
dependencies {
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  compile project(':api')
}

ext {
  GROUP_ID = GROUP
  POM_ARTIFACT_ID = IMPL_POM_ARTIFACT
}

apply from: '../upload.gradle'
```

the `upload.gradle` the script in the SDKProject root directory:

```
  apply plugin: 'maven'

  ext {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    MVN_NAME = properties.getProperty("mvn.dev.user")
    MVN_PASSWORD = properties.getProperty("mvn.dev.password")
  }

  afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                pom.groupId = GROUP_ID
                pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
                pom.version = VERSION_NAME

                repository(url: RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL) {
                  authentication(userName: MVN_NAME, password: MVN_PASSWORD)
                }

                snapshotRepository(url: SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL) {
                  authentication(userName: MVN_NAME, password: MVN_PASSWORD)
                }
              }
          }
    }
    task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
      from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
      classifier = 'sources'
    }

    task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
      failOnError false
      source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
      options {
          charSet = 'UTF-8'
          links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/"
          linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference", System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME") + "/docs/reference"
      }
      classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
      classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    }

    task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
      classifier = 'javadoc'
      from javadoc.destinationDir
    }

    artifacts {
      archives javadocJar
      archives sourcesJar
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by myself through [flat-aar](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar).

And the another way is put Apis code and Impls code in the same module, and write gradle |ike this : [publishing multiple modules to maven](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:publishing_multiple_modules_to_maven), In this way, gradle script will filter out Api and Impl as two module.

#### Finally

I create two sample demonstate for this issue: https://github.com/Jacksgong/gralde-sample